# App crash when add Google Conversion Tracking SDK iOS-3.0.0

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-analytics

I am adding GoogleConversionTrackingSDK into my project and then calling the function: `[ACTConversionReporter reportWithConversionID:@"972050884" label:@"Bzk1CIzPkAkQxKPBzwM" value:@"0" isRepeatable:NO];`
then my app crash. Here is the stack trace:

```
   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSDate act_secondsSince1970]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10225d8d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010210f495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101bd499e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001021a055d +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102100d8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102100938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x00000001000143cb -[ACTReporterPrivate commonQueryParameters] + 84
    6   TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x0000000100014779 -[ACTReporterPrivate report] + 98
    7   TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x000000010001177a -[ACTReporter report] + 75
    8   TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x00000001000118d4 +[ACTConversionReporter reportWithConversionID:label:value:isRepeatable:] + 170
    9   TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x0000000100001de6 -[MoboSDK analytics] + 342
    10  TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x0000000100001c16 __20-[MoboSDK googleSDK]_block_invoke + 38
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001027fd72d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001027ee85f dispatch_once_f + 82
    13  TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x0000000100001bea -[MoboSDK googleSDK] + 122
    14  TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x0000000100001b53 -[MoboSDK init] + 899
    15  TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x0000000100001eb2 __17+[MoboSDK shared]_block_invoke + 50
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001027fd72d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001027ee85f dispatch_once_f + 82
    18  TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x0000000100001e6a +[MoboSDK shared] + 122
    19  TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x000000010000566e -[ViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 254
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010088568b -[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 378
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010087f7be -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenStatusBarAndDeviceAndOrientation:] + 59
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001007b7ef6 -[UIWindow setRootViewController:] + 103
    23  TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x00000001000078f0 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 464
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010077c3d9 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 264
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010077cbe1 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1605
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000100780a0c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 660
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000100791d4c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3189
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000100792216 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 79
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000100782086 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 578
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001035a171a _PurpleEventCallback + 762
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001035a11e1 PurpleEventCallback + 35
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102091679 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010209144e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001020ba903 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001020b9d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    36  UIKit                               0x00000001007802e1 -[UIApplication _run] + 609
    37  UIKit                               0x0000000100781e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    38  TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x000000010000b44a main + 138
    39  TestMoboSDK-Client                  0x00000001000017c4 start + 52
    40  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I also tried a fresh project to add this SDK but got the same crash.If GoogleConversionTrackingSDK-iOS-3.0.0 is support for iOS 7 or not? Need guidance on what am I doing wrong here or if I am missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: Check if you have added all the files needed for the `GoogleConversionTrackingSDK`. `Unrecognized selector error` indicates that you are trying to call a method, whose definition doesn't exist. Try checking for the `act_secondsSince1970` method in the SDK files, and add the corresponding file.

Comment: I added all file of `GoogleConversionTrackingSDK` into my project. Into my project didn't have method `act_secondsSince1970` I think this method is `GoogleConversionTrackingSDK`'s method. But cannot found where it is.

Comment: Did you add the `iOS AdSupport development framework` as mentioned in the [developer link](https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/)?

Comment: Yes, I had added `AdSupport.framework` as mention of the Doc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem appears because google has used categories in static library
The solution is super simple, you need to notify linker about that

[image]

1) Click on the project
2) Click on the target
3) Open `Build Settings` tab
4) Search for `Other Linker Flags`

[image]

5) Double click on `Other Linker Flags`
6) Add `-ObjC` and `-all_load` flags
7)
Remove binary (delete from device/simulator),
Clean project (hitting `cmd+shift+k`) and
build again (hitting `cmd+b`).

You're ready to go!

Comment: Great! add two values `-ObjC` and `-all_load` is can help solved the crash.Before that,I just tried add one of them, so that cannot fix for the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to follow Boudewijn P's suggestion from [here](https://www.en.adwords-community.com/t5/Tracking-Reporting/AdWord-reportWithConversionID-adWordsConversionKey-method-crash/m-p/364264#M13251) ?

> Add -ObjC to the "Other Linker Flags" in the build settings. Or, if
>   you get duplicate symbols, just force load the library by adding
>   -force_load to the other linker flags:
>   -force_load path/to/libGoogleConversionTracking.a replace "path/to" appropriately.

Comment: Yes, I had tried all those advices when I search for this crash, but nothing can help.