# +[UIPasteboard _accessibilityUseQuickSpeakPasteBoard]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, accessibility

I asked this question on Apple Dev forum, but still didn't get an answer.

We expirience 100% iOS 8 devices crash:

```
+[UIPasteboard _accessibilityUseQuickSpeakPasteBoard]: unrecognized selector sent to class
```

The stack trace is:

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2889ec1f __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x36049c8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                 0x288a3f55 __CFExceptionProem
3  CoreFoundation                 0x288a1def ___forwarding___ + 354
4  CoreFoundation                 0x287d3df8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5  UIAccessibility                0x331fc157 +[UIPasteboard_QSExtras pasteboardWithName:create:] + 30
6  MyApp                          0x002eb507 -[TJEventOptimizer .cxx_destruct]
7  MyApp                          0x002eb28b -[TJEventOptimizer .cxx_destruct]
8  MyApp                          0x002f0c2b -[TJEventOptimizer .cxx_destruct]
9  MyApp                          0x002eeedb -[TJEventOptimizer .cxx_destruct]
10 Foundation                     0x295adb5b __NSThread__main__ + 1118
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3670ce93 _pthread_body + 138
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3670ce07 _pthread_start + 118
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3670ab90 thread_start + 8
```

Despite the fact, TapJoy is captured in the stack trace, [their FAQ says](http://tech.tapjoy.com/product-overview/sdk-change-log/sdk-known-issues) it is ocaisonally wrong and has nothing to do with TapJoy's code, but rather iOS 8 bug.

Is it correct?

What accessibility setting related to the crash?

Comment: yea, that's from TapJoy, they are rejecting that issue (saying that it's from Apple side)

Comment: interesting! do you happen to know what accessibility setting + user actions might trigger this?

Comment: Looks to me like something to do with `UIPasteboard_QSExtras`.  Whose code is that?

Comment: @EugeneDubinin please refer to my answer, that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem appears because TapJoy has used categories in static library (that's `UIPasteboard_QSExtras`) 
The solution is super simple, you need to notify linker about that

[image]

1) Click on the project
2) Click on the target
3) Open `Build Settings` tab
4) Search for `Other Linker Flags`

[image]

5) Double click on `Other Linker Flags`
6) Add `-ObjC` and `-all_load` flags
7)
Remove binary (delete from device/simulator),
Clean project (hitting `cmd+shift+k`) and
build again (hitting `cmd+b`).

You're ready to go!

Comment: I had `-ObjC` in there, but not `-all_load`. To be honest, I even don't know how to reproduce it, so can't tell does this fix the issue. Also, your steps include removing binaries, so I wonder, whether user would get this fixed through AppStore update?

Comment: See comment from my previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483123/app-crash-when-add-google-conversion-tracking-sdk-ios-3-0-0/24625961#comment38165198_24625961

Comment: that's happens because UIPasteboard is created only once, to reproduce the crash, change the bundleIdentifier of you application (as I guess)

Comment: Is it essential to Clean the project before building a Release version? I added the -all_load parameter, build and submitted the app. Now it still shows the UIPasteboard crash. The only thing I did differently compared to the Solution is that I didn't clean before building the Release version....

Comment: Hi, I have this exact same issue, and have -ObjC / -all_load flags in there (followed instructions exactly), but am still getting the crash every launch.

Answer (score 1):

the solution suggested by I0gg3r unfortunately does not work.. I tested this on 3 apps, and still find the UIPasteboard crash as most frequent crash.. Any other suggestions? Is there a way to disable the accessibility settings in the app?

**Update**: Tapjoy has released an [update](http://home.tapjoy.com/tech/product-overview/sdk-change-log/ios-change-log-release-notes) (10.2.1) which solves this issue. Please download their latest SDK